# Launch DMG drive script failing after restart

Tags: applescript, automator, script, dmg

I have an automation (screenshots of it here: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0bB-1AiIWdJc1jmkfdjRbsAVA#Launch_Plex_Media_Automation_ )saved as an app in Automator with the following AppleScripts to mount an encrypted DMG file, enter the password in security agent pop up and click OK. macOS is Catalina.

It worked wonderfully for two years. Then it stopped working. After several attempts to fix the script, I went into Time Machine and retrieved the script from a time I knew it was working. It worked great for a bit but now it works a few times then stops entering the password. If I run just the script from Script Editor, it works great. Same if run from Automator. It will continue working in the automation until I shut my MBP down, then it's back to waiting for me to manually enter the password again. The automation has full disk access.

Suggestions to fix this please?

```
tell application "MountDMG"
    activate
end tell

delay 5

tell application "System Events"
    set value of text field 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent" to "Password"
    click button 2 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
    --> button "OK" of window 1 of application process "SecurityAgent"
end tell
```

Comment: Why not just save the _password_ in your keychain?

Comment: Want to avoid that. DMG is my eyes only

Comment: RE: "Want to avoid that. DMG is my eyes only" -- Then I hope you are not saving the "Password" in the _script_, as even set as a Run-only app the password is in plain text.

Comment: Do you need to use MountDMG? If not, you should be able to use something like `printf '%s\0' 'Password' | hdiutil attach -stdinpass /path/to/image.dmg`

Answer (score 0):

I have a sneaky suspicion that this small adjustment may solve your problem.

```
tell application "MountDMG"
    activate
end tell

delay 5

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists of text field 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    set value of text field 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent" to "Password"
    delay 0.1
    click button 2 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
end tell
```

Comment: With the `delay 5` already in the _script_ I be surprised if that `repeat` _loop_ is even necessary, but lets see if it makes a difference for him.

Comment: Thx. I’ll try it.

Comment: no change with the new script.  third time this automation has stopped working after and extended period of time. I was getting a message that the app wasn't allowed assistive access, event though permissions were given. I added ServicesUIAgent, to accessibility as well. this stopped the message but when I restart the MBP it will no longer type in the password. If I type it in manually, dismount the DMG, and run the automation again, it works great. I will screen shot the entire automation and include the link here. Perhaps I have something else that is not set correctly.

Comment: I updated to a simpler script.   tell application “LaunchDmg”
 activate
end tell

delay 5

tell application "System Events"
 set value of text field 1 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent" to “Password”
 click button 2 of window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
 --> button "OK" of window 1 of application process "SecurityAgent"
end tell
I get this message, error "System Events got an error: Can’t set process \"SecurityAgent\" to \”Password\”.” number -10006 from process "SecurityAgent" despite the fact that it did open dmg. but the message stops the next action completing

Comment: After several attempts, deleting the app from assistive access and re-entering it then restarting my MBP seem to fix the problem for now.